# How to secure bitcoin node (bitcoind) that is used only to broadcast transaction?

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, bitcoin.conf, sendrawtransaction

I always wanted to run a bitcoin node at home. But I always worry because it is related with bitcoin (BTC has value).

I have been broadcasting my transaction using Bluewallet by scanning qr code, or copy pasting a signed transaction string. I am wondering if there is any security risk in doing so. From here I thought it's better to set up my own node just to broadcast transaction using `sendrawtransaction`

So I have some questions on what I am about to setup.

1. Is this bitcoin.conf secure for the purpose?

```
# network
testnet=0
#proxy=
#addnode=
#connect
#noirc
maxconnections=20

# JSON-RPC
# accept JSON-RPC?
server=1
rpcuser=secretrpcuser
rpcpassword=secretrpcpassword
#rpctimeout=
rpcport=8332
rpcconnect=192.168.11.5
#rpcssl
daemon=1
```

2. As I disabled rpcssl on my `bitcoin.conf`, is it secure to sendrawtransaction without SSL?
3. Is it more secure to broadcast transaction using `sendrawtransaction` on my private node? Or is it better to do it on public nodes like bluewallet, or sites like pushtx.com or sites lsited here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_broadcasting
4. What are the possible security risks of running own node at home?
5. What are the possible risks on doing `sendrawtransaction` from private home bitcoin node? Also the risk for doing it from public nodes?

Thank you in advance

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you are not using Tor/i2p. Please use Tor: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m afraid to connect to Tor since I watched and read stuffs about the darkweb, there seem to be a lot of illegal and immoral stuffs in there. Don’t want to get involved in there. Is there any risk for running a bitcoin node without tor? And any benefit running it with tor?

Comment: Websites on darknet are completely different thing. You can use Tor as proxy for outbound connections or/and Onion service for incoming connections. This helps in not linking your real IP with transactions. It's easy for anyone to run a Bitcoin node so few will exist to spy and collect information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any security risk if I expose my IP address with my transactions? I think I have been exposing my IP addresses with my transactions using bluewallet, electrum, etc without tor. Should I create a new wallet?